# How can i format the date with Momentjs to look like this?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, momentjs

I used the following date format with a moment to save a date for a document in MongoDB. The problem is that it somehow got converted, I guess by MongoDB. Now if I want to fetch that data by specifying the date, I can't use the same variables I used to create the date in the first place. Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

```
  const date = new Date();
  const firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
  const startDate = moment(firstDay);
  const day = startDate;
```

the day variable is saved in MongoDB as

```
'Wed Jun 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300'
```

But if I try to find the document by date, the day variable is actually returning

```
2020-06-24T22:17:09+03:00
```

I guess what I am trying to do is return today's date in this format `'Wed Jun 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300'` with time set to 0 as I only need the date to search for the document I need.

**EDIT: I was able to do it using Date instead of Momentjs.**

```
  const date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
  console.log(date.toString().split("(Eastern European Summer Time)")[0]);
  //Wed Jun 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0300
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) in aggregation pipeline to achieve it.

Your query might looks similar to this:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ {
   $project: {
      date: {
         $dateFromString: {
            dateString: '$date'
            format:<formatStringExpression>
} ] )
```

From official MongoDB docs:

> New in version 3.6.
>
> Converts a date/time string to a date object.
>
> The $dateFromString expression has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> { $dateFromString: {
>      dateString: <dateStringExpression>,
>      format: <formatStringExpression>,
>      timezone: <tzExpression>,
>      onError: <onErrorExpression>,
>      onNull: <onNullExpression>
> } }
> ```

You might also want to look at [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) in aggregation pipeline, which gives the formatted date string

The syntax is similar to above:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [ {
   $project: {
      date: {
         $dateToString: {
            dateString: '$date'
            format:<formatString>
} ] )
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I'll give this a try. It might actually be a lot better than what i was doing.